# Make a Div move left before it expands

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this `div` that I want to move left, like smoothly with an animation, then I want it to expand to a size with an animation. The way I am currently trying to attempt this is using the classes and switching between them with a **click**, the transition property on them allows for it to animate.

Basically I am struggling with having the element move, Then expand, it wants to either do them at the same time, or expand then when re-clicked it moves.

> I want to Click > move > then expand > then re-click to undo it all.
>   Preferably all in JQuery

HTML:

```
<div class="box" id="box2">
  <h1 class="headline">BOX</h1>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.box_clicked {
    height: 500px;
    width: 500px;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0 , 0, 0.8);
    transition: all 1s;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s;
    -moz-transition: all 1s;
   -o-transition: all 1s;
}
.box {
    height: 200px;
    width: 300px;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0 , 0, 0.8);
    position: relative;
    transition: all 1s;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s;
    -moz-transition: all 1s;
    -o-transition: all 1s;
}

.move-left {
    right: -100px;
    background-color:red;
}
```

here is my [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dps6dwdv/)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There no need to write to much of JS code only we have to do some tricks with CSS3.
Always remember that while using transition on any properties you should have to define initial and final value.
Fiddle for this is https://jsfiddle.net/dps6dwdv/1/

Here is the updated code.

HTML

```
<div class="box" id="box2">
  <h1 class="headline">BOX</h1>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.box {
    height: 200px;
    width: 300px;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0 , 0, 0.8);
    position: relative;
  left: 0px;
    transition: left 1s,width 1s;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s;
    -moz-transition: all 1s;
    -o-transition: all 1s;

}
.box.active{
  left : 20px;
  width : 500px;
}
```

JS

```
$('#box2').click(function(){
    $('#box2').toggleClass("active");

});
```

Comment: This is perfect, simplifies a lot of things. Thanks for teaching me something new!

Comment: There is no need to add duration in `toggleClass()`. It's unnecessary because it doesn't contain duration parameter.

Comment: It resizes and moves simultaneously for me. But you make a good point, you can do it with just transitions if you set a delay.
`transition: left 1s, width 1s ease 1s;`

Answer (score 1):

You can do it all in CSS with a single animation

```js
document.getElementById('button').addEventListener('click',function() {
  document.getElementById('box2').classList.toggle('animate');
})
```

```css
.box {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  position: relative;
  height: 200px;
  width: 300px;
}

input {
  display: none;
}

label {
  cursor: pointer;
  text-decoration: underline;
  color: #09c;
}

:checked ~ #box2, .animate {
  animation: foo 5s forwards;
}

@keyframes foo {
  50% {
    transform: translateX(100px);
    height: 200px;
    width: 300px;
  }
  100% {
    height: 500px;
    width: 500px;
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox"><label for="checkbox">checkbox</label> <button id="button">javascript</button>
<div class="box" id="box2">
  <h1 class="headline">BOX</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: this has no event listener, needs to be click based

Comment: @Jiroscopes edited my answer and added a couple of methods to trigger the animation. the checkbox method is all CSS, and the other method uses javascript.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this

```js
var bind = true
$('#box2').click(function() {
  $('#box2').toggleClass("box box_clicked");
});

$('#box2').click(function() {
  if (bind) {
    $('#box2').addClass("move-left");
  }
  else $('#box2').removeClass("move-left");
  bind = !bind;
});
```

```css
.box_clicked {
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  transition: all 1s;
  -webkit-transition: all 1s;
  -moz-transition: all 1s;
  -o-transition: all 1s;
}
.box {
  height: 200px;
  width: 300px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  position: relative;
  left: 0px;
  transition: all 1s;
  -webkit-transition: all 1s;
  -moz-transition: all 1s;
  -o-transition: all 1s;
}
.move-left {
  position: relative;
  left: 100px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box" id="box2">
  <h1 class="headline">BOX</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: this would work, how can I make it return to its original state when clicked again?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using keyframe animations.

```js
var box = document.getElementById('box2');
box.addEventListener('click', function() {
  box.classList.toggle('box_clicked');
});
```

```css
@keyframes boxActivated {
  50% {
    transform: translateX(100px);
  }
  100% {
    height: 500px;
    width: 500px;
    transform: translateX(100px);
  }
}

.box {
  height: 200px;
  width: 300px;
  right: 0;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0 , 0, 0.8);
  position: relative;
}

.box_clicked {
  animation-name: boxActivated;
  animation-duration: 4s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
```

```html
<div class="box" id="box2">
    <h1 class="headline">BOX</h1>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you expecting something like this ? Using `JQuery`

```js
var bind = true



$('#box2').click(function() {

  $('#box2').css({
    'right': '0px',
    'left': '0px'
  }).animate({
    'right': '150px'
  }, function(){ $(this).addClass("box_clicked").css({'height':'100px'})});

  
});

$('#box2').click(function() {
  if (bind) {

    $('#box2').css({
      'right': '0px',
      'left': '0px'
    }).animate({
      'left': '150px'
    },0, function(){  $(this).addClass("move-left").css({'height':'200px'})});
  }
  bind = !bind;
});
```

```css
.box_clicked {
height: 100px;
width: 200px;
background-color: rgba(0, 0 , 0, 0.8);
transition: all 1s;
-webkit-transition: all 1s;
-moz-transition: all 1s;
-o-transition: all 1s;
}
.box {
height: 100px;
width: 200px;
background-color: rgba(0, 0 , 0, 0.8);
position: relative;
transition: all 1s;
-webkit-transition: all 1s;
-moz-transition: all 1s;
-o-transition: all 1s;

}

.move-left {
right: -100px;
background-color:red;

 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box" id="box2">
  <h1 class="headline">BOX</h1>
</div>
```